# Solving for angles on a circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given that $\widehat {AD}$ is $80^\circ$, solve for angle $1$,  $\widehat {CB}$, angle $P$, angle $A$ and angle $D$.

From the figure I can only deduce that angle $1$ is $40%\circ$ as well as $\angle ABD$... but further than that i do not have idea how to solve for the rest. Any help?

Comment: If we fix $A$ and $D$, and move $P$ closer to the circle, then the arc $CB$ will get smaller, and angle $P$ will get bigger. So we can't solve for those exactly. We need at least one more given.

Comment: The problem is not solvable: too few data